# Has anyone seen a SharePoint site integrated with interactive floor plans?

Tags: office, directory

I would love to add interactive office floor plans to my SharePoint portal.  I would like to be able to hotlink directly from my employee directory to a dynamic floor plan showing where they sit.  Anyone done this?

Comment: If you have the enterprise version, Visio services can be used for that (I've done exactly what you are trying to do for a customer of mine)

Comment: Agreed - I presented this at the SharePoint Conference in Sydney and Auckland too.  Interaction is even better if you use the JS API for Visio.

Comment: Dave will tell: I've done that, too. SharePoint list linked to Visio drawing. Select name in list, see desk light up in drawing. Different approach than Dave. No API. Technique outlined here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umId-epzsfc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen a third party app which does this quite nicely: Floor Plan Mapper [Floor Plan Mapper](http://www.floorplanmapper.com)

Answer (score 2):

The article below describes how to configure a floor plan in SharePoint with the help of [Plumsail Dashboard Designer](http://spchart.com):

https://plumsail.com/blog/2016/11/floor-plan-with-dashboard-designer-for-sharepoint-and-office-365/

Answer (score 0):

I'm with OfficeSpace Software and this is exactly what our software does in a clean elegant easy to use interface. [www.officespacesoftware.com](http://www.officespacesoftware.com) and in fact StackExchange is a client of ours :)  [I have their permission to mention them]

Comment: Just because David works for OfficeSpaceSoftware, doesn't make his answer invalid IMHO.

Comment: He disclosed his affiliation and the software does what the OP asked, this is fine per our guidelines.